# Clion is not showing errors for header files without source file

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I recently switched from visual studio to clion cause I'm used to jetbrains products more. I noticed, that header file needs to have source file to show me errors.

[image]

This line is clearly wrong, but clion doesn't care. My cmake:

```
set(ALL_FILES
        ....
        src/....../ttest.h)
```

When I add a .cpp file:

```
...
src/....../ttest.cpp src/....../ttest.h
```

It works just fine:

[image]

Why is that? I have a lot of header-only files. Thanks.

Comment: Is the header with a error included somewhere? Anyways, I doubt this is related to `cmake`.

Comment: Yes, it is included. This same thing happens with already existing files when I changed the IDE to clion. But only to some of them. The output from cmake:


"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" D:\FoxEngine
x64 architecture in use
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/FoxEngine/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]

Comment: Intellisense in visual studio uses alternative parsing engine so it can deal relatively good with arbitrary files while clion is built on top of cmake and clangd so it can only deal with files that are listed in the current cmake "project" and are included into one of the translation units in this project. Basically information about header files is extracted and analysis is performed when compiling translation unit. So your only choice is to create a dummy translation unit and include all your stray header files there.